# BeautifulSoup get href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a href from a website. When I insepct the page in Chrome, I see this:

```
<div>
  <strong>Services</strong>
  <p class="pdflink"><a href="http://shopalpha.com/services/&amp;fileId=12345&amp;_ga=1.255686972.2435297996.2694961543-2467379995.2693735225" target="_blank">Services week 11 pdf</a></p>
</div>
```

But when I am trying to get that url in my script using beautifulsoup, I don't get the whole url, just this:

```
>>> print soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'pdflink'}).find('a', href=True)['href']
http://shopalphalc.com/services/&amp;fileId=12345
```

I dont know if the url is modified in some way when loading the page, but is there a way to get the full url using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I have tried your code and it gives full href, checks your code once again

Comment: I tried to curl the url and then I only get http://shopalphalc.com/services/&amp;fileId=12345 in the html downloaded so I guess they append something to the url since when I inspect it in chrome, I see something else. Can this be solved in some way? I would prefer not to use selenium or something similar.

Comment: print your 'soup` and check what is the href of link. if it's seen in your inspect in the browser then it takes time to load and it's come from js in a page.

Comment: can you share the url and full code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the urllib.parse library to decode the URL and get the complete and correctly formatted link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote

# Sample HTML
html = '''
<div>
  <strong>Services</strong>
  <p class="pdflink"><a href="http://shopalpha.com/services/&amp;fileId=12345&amp;_ga=1.255686972.2435297996.2694961543-2467379995.2693735225" target="_blank">Services week 11 pdf</a></p>
</div>
'''

# Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Get the href attribute value
href = soup.find('p', class_='pdflink').find('a')['href']

# Decode the URL
decoded_href = unquote(href)

print(decoded_href)
```

Output:

```
http://shopalpha.com/services/&fileId=12345&_ga=1.255686972.2435297996.2694961543-2467379995.2693735225
```